# Finding the nth occurrence of a number using regex

Tags: regex, count, numbers

I am trying to write a regex that can find the nth occurrence of a number match (where N is a number that can increment in a for loop). I can get the regex to successfully match a number, but I can't get it to match a specific number in the sequence. The regex I used is `([0-9]+){2}`.

What I am trying to do is pick out the number out of a string like: Red,12,Green,5,Blue,6

Using a regex that can pick out, 12 then, 2, then 3. I was hoping the `{n}` part of the regex could accomplish this, but when I set that number to 2 for instance, instead of picking out the number 5 as expected, it picks up the 2 in 12, and when I set the number to 3, it is unable to find a match at all. Could anyone provide any insight into what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this regex to pick `N`th number:

```
(?:\D*(\d+)){2}
```

Replace `2` by any number you want. Your number is available in captured group #1

- `\D` matches any non-digit
- `\d` matches a digit

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qX1bH9/1)

Comment: This community is amazing! Thank you, this worked perfectly

Comment: Thank you very much helped me out to get something that matches every Nth semicolon!
https://regex101.com/r/10pZFD/1

Comment: @rufreakde: You may just use `(?:[^;]*;){10}`

Comment: @anubhava you are correct if I just want the slices yes. ( ). in my solution just gives me the matched ';' back as well.